# Splitting and inserting a string in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table called `LOG` that has a column named `MESSAGE`, which is a `VARCHAR2(4000)`. 
Since I'm planning a migration and the column `MESSAGE` in the new database is a `VARCHAR2(2000)`, I want to iterate over all `MESSAGE` rows with length > 2000 and substring the text after 2000 characters and insert everything of the text that comes after 2000 characters into a new row. 
I also have to update the original rows to have 2000 chars.

How can I do this? It's been really a long time since I worked with PL/SQL, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Suppose you do that. In the new database, how will you know which row contains the first 2000 characters and which row contains the remaining part of the `MESSAGE`? Do you need an additional column to show `part 1` and `part 2`? It seems it would be a lot easier to change the column in the "receiving" table to `VARCHAR2(4000)`, is that an option? (If not, why not?)

Comment: There is also a segment ID, thus it's not a problem. I can't change it to VARCHAR2(4000) because of the character encoding.

Comment: Isn't it just one `insert` and one `update`? I'm not seeing the complication.

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select . . ., substr(l.message, 1, 2000) as message
from log l
union all
select . . ., substr(l.message, 2001, 2000) as message
from log l
where lenght(l.message) > 2000;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But how can I insert the `substr(l.message, 2001, 4000)` part now in a new row?

Comment: @Javiator . . . You can put `insert` before this statement.

Comment: How does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

It can also easily be done with a `connect by` as it demonstrates in this example where it should split after every 5th character:

```
select substr(test.test, (level-1)*5, 5)
from (select 'THIS IS A LONG MESSAGE ACTUALLY' test from dual) test
connect by substr(test.test, (level-1)*5, 5) IS NOT NULL
```

in this scenario you wouldn´t even have to bother about anything at it would automaticly seperate the values no matter if they are longer than 2000 or not.

```
select substr(l.message, (level-1)*2000, 2000) message
from log l
substr(l.message, (level-1)*2000, 2000) IS NOT NULL
```

This could be your final select.

Comment: Character positions in Oracle strings begin with 1, rather than 0. The way you wrote this, the first string will have length 4, not 5. To fix it, add 1 to the second argument of `substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved using a `PLSQL` block as below. Please try to implement the logic mentioned inline and check if this works.

Code:

```
 declare
  ---getting each message of length 4000 characters
  cursor cur is 
  select message 
  from log;

   var number;                 
   var1 varchar2(2000);
   cntr number:=0;
begin
  --Loop for each message 
  for i in cur
   loop                
      --getting length of message
     var:= length(i.message);

       for len in 1..(var / 2000)
        loop
            --setting the offset to pick 2000 chracters
            if cntr = 0 then
             cntr := cntr +1;
            else 
              cntr := cntr + 2000;
            end if;  

            --selecting 2000 characters from message 
            var1:=substr(i.message,cntr,2000);

             ---inserting 2000 charcters to table
            insert into table_log(col1) 
            values(var1 );

             commit;
        end loop;

    end loop;

end;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> create table log(message varchar2(4000));

SQL> select message from log ;

MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KHAGDKAGDHAGDKHAGD
ADSJHA:DAH:DHHAHDH
.
.
.
SQL> select length(message) from log ;

LENGTH(MESSAGE)
---------------
           3989

SQL> create  table table_log(col1 varchar2(2000));


SQL> select col1 from table_log ;

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

 --- Two rows created to destination table with size approx 2000 characters each
SQL> select length(col1) from table_log ;

LENGTH(COL1)
------------
        2000
        1989
```

In Simple SQL you can do it as

```
insert into table_log(col1) 
select SUBSTR(l.MESSAGE, 1, 2000) AS MESSAGE
FROM LOG l
UNION ALL
select  SUBSTR(l.MESSAGE, 2001, 2000) AS MESSAGE
FROM LOG l
WHERE length(l.MESSAGE) > 2000;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solves the problem, however in my situation this not very efficient, as I have about 20 million rows to process.

Comment: SQL will always be faster than PLSQL. I replied coz you mentioned you wanted to do in PLSQL.

Comment: How would you do that in SQL?

Comment: Right..It will not update original rows..It will insert 2 rows for each 1 row in your target table..

Comment: Yes, I see that. But I have to do that on my source table first. Sorry I think I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Well in that case you will need to update your source with first 2000 characters and then insert again 2000 characters. Which will be an costly thing. You can do one thing just populate the target table with 2 rows and then rename it to source and drop the original source.

Comment: Could you please show me how I could do that? I mean first shorten the message to 2000 chars, and insert the rest in a new row?

Comment: I meant to say, why dont you follow this. Just create a new target table and with the SQL query given above you populate the new table and then drop the original table. Rename the new table. That would be easier. Again shortening and inserting would need a PLSQL or a temporary table to hold the intermediate result.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will think about your suggested approach an test it :)

Comment: Let me know if that worked..Coz am sure that will work and its the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You can split rows during copying to new table. For this you should use  `INSERT ALL WHEN`.  For each WHEN clause whose condition evaluates to true, the database executes the corresponding INTO clause list.

```
create table src_test_table(long_msg varchar2(20));
create table dest_test_table(long_msg varchar2(10));

insert into src_test_table values(lpad('1',20,'1'));
insert into src_test_table values(lpad('2',20,'2'));
insert into src_test_table values(lpad('3',20,'3'));
insert into src_test_table values(lpad('4',10,'4'));
insert into src_test_table values(lpad('5',10,'5'));

insert all 
 when length(long_msg) <= 10 then 
    into dest_test_table values(long_msg)
 when length(long_msg) > 10 then 
    into dest_test_table values(substr(long_msg,1,10))   
 when length(long_msg) > 10 then 
    into dest_test_table values(substr(long_msg,11))   
select long_msg from  src_test_table;
```

And results;

`select long_msg,length(long_msg) from dest_test_table;`